# Ошибка zip (короткий код)

Tags: python, zip

```
import os
import time

source = ['"D:\\Backup_file\\message"']

target_dir = 'D:\\Backup\\Reserve'

today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)
print('Каталог успешно создан', today)

target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии не удалось!')
```

Каталог успешно создан D:\Backup\Reserve\20190918
"zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Создание резервной копии не удалось!

---

Бал установлен WinRar,решил установить 7-Zip,а ошибка все равно осталась.
Потом скачал GnuWin32 и добавил путь к системной переменной окружения PATH,но все равно не помогло.
[image: Потом скачал GnuWin32 и добавил путь к системной переменной окружения PATH]

Comment: @Joker судя по ошибке, то, что вы написали, совсем не очевидно.

Comment: Если вы в командной строке введете команду `zip`, ошибка повторится? Если да, то это _очевидно_ не проблема python.

Comment: Если каталог с вызываемой программой (zip) присутствует в %PATH%, то, возможно, нужна перезагрузка системы. Для проверки надо запустить командную оболочку и ввести zip, если появится ошибка перезагрузиться и проверить снова. На крайний случай можно использовать полный путь к zip.

Comment: Все равно не помогло,менял путь к zip,перезагружал систему,а ошибка все равно осталась(

Comment: Сама-то программа zip запускается, если её вызвать из проводника? Возможно проблемы с самим исполняемым файлом. В конце концов, можно использовать вместо zip - 7z или Rar раз они установлены, всего лишь изменив параметры их запуска.